# GTM OAuth Twitter update error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oauth, nsurlconnection, google-toolbox-for-mac

I'm having a posting issue with the gtm oauth toolbox. I've been trying to send a tweet to twitter but I keep getting authorization errors. Right now I'm receiving the following error with the code below "POST error: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)"

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"status=thisisatest"]; 
NSString *urlStr = @"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]; 
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher 
                             fetcherWithRequest:request]; 
[myFetcher setAuthorizer: mAuth]; 
[myFetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *retrievedData, 
                                             NSError *error) 
 { 
     if (error != nil) 
     { 
         NSLog(@"POST error: %@", error); 
     } 
     else 
     { 
         NSDictionary *results = [[[[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
                                    retrievedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease] JSONValue]; 
         NSLog(@"POST Successful: #%@ @ %@", [results objectForKey: 
                                              @"id"], [results objectForKey: @"created_at"]); 
     } 
 }];
```

What am I doing wrong here? The token is already stored in the keychain. Do I need to retrieve the keychain token or does gtm sign the request automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the issue. I missed a place in one of the GTM .m files for the consumer key. That's what I get for rushing things. :-)